# How to use multiple .go files in the same application

Tags: go

Good Morning All,

I am new to Golang. I want to move some of my functions out into separate files so that I will not have like a 10,000 line .go file at the end. lol. I created two files both have the same package called main. Do I need to change package name to be app specific? Anyway how do I get these two files to talk?

Example:

MainFile.go:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello World!")

    Test()
}
```

NewFile.go:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func Test() {
    fmt.Println("Hello World Again!")
}
```

The test method is in the second file but cannot be reached by the first. I am sure this is some rudimentary thing I am missing.

Thanks

**Update: 
I tried specifying this on the command line: go build MainFile.go NewSourceFile.go. It comes back with no errors but never builds the binary. How do I get it to output the binary now?**

Comment: Are you using `go run`? Are the files in the same folder?

Comment: You can put multiple files of the same package *in the same folder* . Put your `MainFile.go` and `NewFile.go` in a folder, eg. `MyProg`. If you run `go build` in the `MyProg` folder, an executable (`MyProg.exe` on windows) will be created.

Comment: I get the following error when I try and run go build MainFile.go.

# command-line-arguments
.\MainFile.go:10: undefined: Test

Comment: Also yes they are in the same folder. They both have the same package name as well.

Comment: Run `go build` not `go build MainFile.go`

Answer (score 2):

If you run `go run MainFile.go`, `Test()` won't be found because its not in that file. You have to build the package then run the package:

Inside the folder where the 2 files are, run `go build` and you will get a binary in that folder.  Then just run the binary:  `./MyPackage`

Comment: I get the following error when I try and run go build MainFile.go. # command-line-arguments .\MainFile.go:10: undefined: Test

Comment: Just run 'go build' inside the directory. Do not specify the file. You are building the package not a specific file. If all is well, you will see nothing on the terminal. if you 'ls' (or dir in windows), you will see that a binary file has been created. Now run the binary file.

Comment: I ran the 'go build' in the directory like you said and no errors were displayed on the console. No binary file was created either. I checked the root of the GOPATH and in the directory and no file. I specified -o Test.exe and it created a 8KB file that was not runnable though. So I am still not sure what I am doing wrong

Comment: This is the correct answer. OP clearly has a system configuration issue going on.

Comment: @JoshC - What does your path look like? You should be in /{{your go folder}}/src/{{your package folder name/{{MainFile.go and NewFile.go here}}

cd into that folder and then type: go build and you should get the {{package folder}}.exe file that is much larger than 8kb.